# Executing and automatically storing all error messages into file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Is there an easy way to execute a python script and then have all error messages save to a type of log file (csv, txt, anything).

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, something):
        self.something = something

    def my_function(self):
        # code here
```

Or is the only way to add try and except statements everywhere and write the error messages to a file?

Comment: I think you're looking for the logging module: https://realpython.com/python-logging/

Comment: Are the errors something you are throwing / checking yourself or do you want to generally store to disk whatever gets written to `STDERR` by a certain script?

Comment: @norok2 - not too sure what `STDERR` is

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that using python logging

Answer (score 0):

Here's a specific example, using the info from https://realpython.com/python-logging/ with your code:

```
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', filemode='w', format='%(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
logging.warning('This will get logged to a file')

class MyClass():
     def __init__(self, something):
          self.something = something

     def my_function(self):
          logging.warning('my_function entered...')
```

After you instantiate your class and call my_function, you should get logging output in your log file (here app.log):

```
root - WARNING - This will get logged to a file
root - WARNING - my_function entered...
```